# Dynamic Z-Ordering in Java Game Engine

Tags: java, drawing, game-engine

I'm building a basic Java 2D game framework, but I'm unsure of the best way to render my objects efficiently with z-ordering.  The only solutions that came mind were either

- Using an ArrayList to store the objects and sorting them with a Comparator by depth when changes were made
- Using an ArrayList to hold HashSets of objects that belong to the same depth

The idea is to keep the objects ordered so that the rendering object will only need to loop through the objects and render them.  The sorting can be handled by something else.

The first option requires constant sorting of the ArrayList whenever objects are added, removed, or moved to a different depth.  The second option only needs to move individual objects to different HashSets when there's a depth change, but more memory is used (depending on the number of depths).

Which solution (alternative solutions are also very welcome) would be the most logical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most games, ordering of the objects is quite constant. Only once in a while a single object Z order is changed. Using a `ArrayList` for this would usually do the work. Notice that there is no need of constant sorting. You add the objects sorted only at the beginging. Then, you simply add/move a single object to it location in the `ArrayList`.

Make sure to use synchronized list, or another method to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` as the GUI thread is scanning the list, while another thread is changing it.

Comment: I suspected that I was over-thinking it.  Thank you!